# How do I set up my build.gradle repos to pull these from our internal Nexus repo?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This is not a question about Nexus setup, but `build.gradle` setup.

I set up an internal Nexus repo, and our Gradle builds get 99% of the artifacts from our internal Nexus repo. However, I'm still seeing these downloads from external repos, for example. I have both https://plugins.gradle.org/m2 and https://repo1.maven.org/maven2 defined in my Nexus repo.

I have this in my `build.gradle`

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url "https://ourNexusRepo.company.com"
        credentials {
            username "user"
            password "password"
        }
    }
}


Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-loader-tools/1.4.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-loader-tools-1.4.6.RELEASE.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/spring/gradle/dependency-management-plugin/0.6.1.RELEASE/dependency-management-plugin-0.6.1.RELEASE.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-node-plugin/1.1.1/gradle-node-plugin-1.1.1.pom
Download https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/moowork/gradle/gradle-node-plugin/1.1.1/gradle-node-plugin-1.1.1.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-parent/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-parent-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/4.3.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.3.6.RELEASE.pom
```

What am I missing in `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 0):

This is part of an answer. I'll update it once I find out the reason.

Plugins are managed by the `pluginManagement{}` block in `settings.gradle`, like so

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
      url "https://ourNexusRepo.company.com"
      credentials {
        username "user"
        password "password"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Our Gradle plugins are are now downloaded from within our internal repo. However, I still see these

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-tools/1.4.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-tools-1.4.4.RELEASE.pom
```